# How to Swipe Images (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, swipe, android-gallery

i created a image grid-view app and i want to swipe grid-view images in full screen.

i want to swipe images in left and right both direction.

i found swipe image code from search:

i am beginner in android programing so i don't know how do i implement this code in my app code.

so i need help to implement this swipe code in my app.

**Swipe Image Code**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.sqisland.android.swipe_image_viewer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
  {
    private int[] mImages = new int[] 
    {
        R.drawable.chiang_mai,
        R.drawable.himeji,
        R.drawable.petronas_twin_tower,
        R.drawable.ulm
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
      return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
    {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
      Context context = MainActivity.this;
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
          R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**my app code (image grid-view)**

**MainActivity,java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView photoGrid;
    private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    // Some items to add to the GRID
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean",
            "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean",
            "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Britney Spears",
            "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary",
            "Micheal Buble" };
    private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] { R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin,
            R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary,
            R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright,
            R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb,
            R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon,
            R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney,
            R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin,
            R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary,
            R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright,
            R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb,
            R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon,
            R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney,
            R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the photo size and spacing
        mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
        mPhotoSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);

        // initialize image adapter
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

        photoGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

        // set image adapter to the GridView
        photoGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        // get the view tree observer of the grid and set the height and numcols dynamically
        photoGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                    final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(photoGrid.getWidth() / (mPhotoSize + mPhotoSpacing));
                    if (numColumns > 0) {
                        final int columnWidth = (photoGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mPhotoSpacing;
                        imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                        imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // ///////// ImageAdapter class /////////////////
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mItemHeight = 0;
        private int mNumColumns = 0;
        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }

        // set numcols
        public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
            mNumColumns = numColumns;
        }

        public int getNumColumns() {
            return mNumColumns;
        }

        // set photo item height
        public void setItemHeight(int height) {
            if (height == mItemHeight) {
                return;
            }
            mItemHeight = height;
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (view == null)
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, null);

            ImageView cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

            cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

            // Check the height matches our calculated column width
            if (cover.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
                cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            }

            cover.setImageResource(ICONS[position % ICONS.length]);
            title.setText(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/albumGrid"
    style="@style/PhotoGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/photo_size"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/photo_spacing"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/photo_spacing" />
```

**photo_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/album_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cover"
        android:background="#70000000"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please guide me how do i implement / adjust swipe image code in my grid-view app code.

so when i click / tab a image in grid-view it should open in swipe able full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make changes in your image grid-view code
 **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView photoGrid;
    private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    // Some items to add to the GRID
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] 
            { 
            "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean",
            "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean",
            "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon",
            "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Britney Spears",
            "Hilary", "Micheal Buble", "Akon", "Justin Bieber", "AlRight", "Big Sean", "Britney Spears", "Hilary",
            "Micheal Buble" 
            };
    static final int[] ICONS = new int[] 
            { 
            R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin,
            R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary,
            R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright,
            R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb,
            R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon,
            R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney,
            R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin,
            R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary,
            R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon, R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright,
            R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb,
            R.drawable.cover_britney, R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb, R.drawable.cover_akon,
            R.drawable.cover_justin, R.drawable.cover_alright, R.drawable.cover_big_sean, R.drawable.cover_britney,
            R.drawable.cover_hilary, R.drawable.cover_mb 
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the photo size and spacing
        mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
        mPhotoSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);

        // initialize image adapter
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

        photoGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

        //start sent image to full screen             

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        photoGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SwipeActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //end sent image to full screen

        // set image adapter to the GridView
        photoGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        // get the view tree observer of the grid and set the height and numcols dynamically
        photoGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                    final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(photoGrid.getWidth() / (mPhotoSize + mPhotoSpacing));
                    if (numColumns > 0) {
                        final int columnWidth = (photoGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mPhotoSpacing;
                        imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                        imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // ///////// ImageAdapter class /////////////////
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mItemHeight = 0;
        private int mNumColumns = 0;
        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }

        // set numcols
        public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
            mNumColumns = numColumns;
        }

        public int getNumColumns() {
            return mNumColumns;
        }

        // set photo item height
        public void setItemHeight(int height) {
            if (height == mItemHeight) {
                return;
            }
            mItemHeight = height;
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (view == null)
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, null);

            ImageView cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

            cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

            // Check the height matches our calculated column width
            if (cover.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
                cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            }

            cover.setImageResource(ICONS[position % ICONS.length]);
            title.setText(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

create a class 
**SwipeActivity.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class SwipeActivity extends Activity 
{   

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe_view);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
  {
      int[] icons = MainActivity.ICONS;    

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
      return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
    {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
    {
      Context context = SwipeActivity.this;
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
          R.dimen.padding_large);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
    {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
}
```

create layout **swipe_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

create **dimens.xml** under res/values (for paddin)

```
<dimen name="padding_small">4dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="padding_medium">8dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="padding_large">16dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library, [Draggable Grid View](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView)

I think this should solve your problem. Don't forget to vote up in case this solves your problem.